# java method overloading: abnormal behaviour

Tags: java, overloading

I tried two cases as below:

```
void ssss(int b){
   System.out.println ("int"+b);
}
void ssss(double b){
   System.out.println ("long"+b);
}
```

and made a method call as

```
ssss(100);
```

This worked fine.

```
void calcAve(double marks1, int marks2) {
   System.out.println ("first average");
}
void calcAve(int marks1, double marks2) {
   System.out.println ("second average");
}
```

and made a method call as

```
calcAve(2,3);
```

This returned a compilation error: reference to calcAve is ambiguous.

Understand why the second gets a compilation error. My question is using the same analogy, the first case also should return an error but that is not the case. Why??

Comment: because 2 can be a valid int or double

Comment: Because you have 2 overloaded methods that can take ints. (double,int) as well as(int, double). Like @getlost says, `2` can be considered as an `int` as well as a `double` .

Comment: In second case you are doing mismatch of datatype

Comment: you should tell what is double what is int. may be cast calcAve((int)2,3);

Answer (score 4):

Intuitively, in the first case there is an exact type match, whereas in the second case there are two inexact matches that are equally good (either of the two `int`s can be promoted to `double`).

The exact rules are rather complicated, but you can find them in the JLS: [§15.12.2. Compile-Time Step 2: Determine Method Signature](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2).

One way to resolve the ambiguity is by changing the type of the of the arguments:

```
calcAve(2.0, 3);
calcAve(2, 3.0);
```

Answer (score 1):

because your arguments match by both methods
you should tell what is int what is double
2 is valid double as well as int

try that

```
calcAve((int)2,(double)3);
```

Answer (score 0):

In java, if you pass a Integer value as a parameter you can simply pass it and compiler is compiling that integer value as 32 bit int value. If you want to pass a Long value as a parameter you have to add "L" at the end of the value like 200L. Then compiler compiles it as 64 bit long value.

Normally floating point values are compiling as double value. If you want to pass a double value as a parameter you can simply pass it as 200. Then compiler compile is as 64 bit double value. If you want to pass a float value as a parameter then you have to add "F" at the end of the value like 200F. Then compiler compiles it as float value(32 bit)

In your case, both argument list are compatible with parameter list. That is why compiler can not identify the exact one.

If you pass the double value as 2.0 then you can execute the method that you want to execute